# What is this WWII four-engine plane on skis?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, wwii

I've seen this plane but I don't know its name:

[image: to be identified aircraft]

Comment: Could you add a source for the image? A Google reverse image search finds **World of Warships Arctic**. Are you sure this is a real aircraft and not just from a game?

Comment: @Bianfable **World of Warships Arctic** makes a lot of sense, as that game focuses on the time period where this kind of machine could have seen action. Also, the bit of UI in the lower right gives it away :)

Comment: Yep, that's straight out of World of Warships. It's part of the pregame screen for a match on the Arctic map.

Comment: Note that the fantasy skis there are utterly impossible.  They would ***dig in to the snow!!***  A wedge is ***precisely the opposite*** of a ski  :)  :)   Heh!

Comment: Well, I think.  I may be wrong, it may just be capturing the wrong angle.

Answer (score 22):

Looks like a [TB-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_TB-3) or a variant thereof. According to Wikipedia, this four-engine all steel(!) heavy bomber first flew in 1930 and was the world's first cantilever aircraft in this class. The skis do not appear to have pertained exclusively to any specific variant, given that the first flight already used them.

It was used up to and including the Second World War, and a number of experimental variants were developed from it. One of the most interesting was the [Zveno project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zveno_project), an experiment with parasite fighters. Here you can see the Zveno-SPB variant of the TB-3 with two [I-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polikarpov_I-16) fighters under the wings:

[image]

The Zveno-SPB saw operational usage and even success in raids against the Romanian oilfields during WW2.

Comment: Oh man, a bomber that drops fighters that drop bombs...

Comment: @Jpe61 6D chess :) The USAF also [experimented with this concept later on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FICON_project), and came to similar conclusions.

Comment: @AEhere wonder why the USAF thought 6 inches of ground clearance was a problem :)

Comment: @Jpe61 Yo dawg, I herd you like bombers...

Comment: @jwenting indeed, I've seen less on modern-day hardware.

Comment: @AEhere the USAF can't assume it's airfields are perfectly smooth pavement.  They (and most other military operators) design around higher ground clearances so they can keep flying after just bulldozing most of the rubble back into the bomb craters and maybe dropping a steel plate on top to partially counter the roughness.

Comment: @DanNeely while my comment was mostly joking, the hardware I referenced was military in nature. Excessive optimism is not unknown in this area.

Answer (score 19):

As yury10578 and AEhere correctly pointed out it's ANT-6A "Aviaarctica", polar version of TB-3 heavy bomber. (The plane's name is written on its body)

Its drawing in that exact livery:
[image: ANT-6A drawing]

ANT-6A with ski-only landing gear:

[image: ANT-6A]

Comment: *"Its drawing in that exact livery"* Well, not *exact*. The OP's image has yellow accents. But quite close.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, missed that. That's probably just some inconsistency of the drawings. Another [drawing](http://img.wp.scn.ru/camms/ar/660/pics/1_o_3.jpg) has something like those accents.

Answer (score 1):

That must be one of the civil variants of TB-3 as other guys already said. Went under designations ANT-6A and/or G-2, I'd have to dig out a book to tell more precisely.

Interestingly, Wikipedia tells almost nothing about it -- and this plane (well, planes -- there were a small series) was quite a hero of Artic flights, if I recall my reading right.

ADDED: Well, it was (a hero etc.). On May 21, 1937 ANT-6A commanded by M.V.Vodopyanov (aircraft register number N-170) made ice landing in the North pole region, the first in history. Later, flight of 4 ANT-6A's landed the "North pole-1" polar expedition and their supplies.
The ANT-6A (actually, ANT-6 "Aviaarktika") modifications included a drag chute, which allowed to reduce a landing run by 35-50%. These aircraft could have either wheeled or ski landing gear. The cargo weight was up to 2500 kg, while the total load could reach almost 50% of takeoff weight.
G-2, however, and here I was wrong, was essentially TB-3 without the armament and with added cargo securing equipment and some "passenger carrying equipment"--hard seats (up to 4000 kg load or up to 50 passengers). Some of those registered thousands of flight hours.